# App crashed after inserting duplicate values for composite key in room db in Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I make a composite key of two columns when I 1st time the data goes well. But when I insert the same data (duplicate) the app crashed.
How to handle the app not to crash after inserting duplicate data? Just give me a toast message "Data available already"

```
@Entity(tableName = "ChildRegistration",
        indices = {@Index(value = {"childName","mobileNumber"}, unique = true)})

public class ChildRegistration {}`
```

Comment: Can you give the error logged to console?

Comment: how about checking through Query? select count(*) where blablabla

Comment: @Enayat afridi thanks it worked. and thanks guys.@TheDongster room db have pre defined methods which can handle these errors

Answer (score 1):

Use `onConflict = OnCnflictStrategy.IGNORE` and make insert method to return long. If insertion returns -1, it means already exists. Otherwise it will return the row number that inserted.

Comment: Thanks Enayat. appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that unique is set to true therefore you'll have to have confict resolution. The examples I gave below come directly from the official documentation on the links i gave

For example in your dao

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE) suspend fun insert(word: Word)
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Update#onConflict()

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#4

Or update one that already exist for example

```
@Update public void updateSong(Song)
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Update

Comment: Thanks Nada it worked just like i asked for. thank so much

Comment: @ShahHaroon ok. You are welcome. You can close the question a select the answer that helped you

Comment: Ok bro. Thanks again